# Field update after approval process

Tags: workflow, approval-process

I am having an existing process where a trigger triggers a approval process. After the approver clicks for approve a field called Approval_Status__c should be checked.

I wrote a workflow but seems like not working

This is the formula i evaluate to update a field Approval_Status__c= true, when Opportunity_Status__c = Application Support Request Approved.

Opportunity_Status__c is a picklist value.

```
OR((PRIORVALUE(Opportunity_Status__c)== 'Application Support Request Approved'), ISPICKVAL(Opportunity_Status__c, 'Application Support Request Approved'))
```

Comment: We will need to see relevant implementation and issue details to be able to provide any direction.

Comment: I would recommend adding in more information on your use case, as well as anything you have already tried and relevant code examples. See here for more info: [salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Post approval updates should be considered within the approval process itself and not with Workflow. Consider adding a new **Final Approval Action** with a type of *Field Update*.

[image]

Comment: While this answer may provide a path to resolution but I think we will need to wait for OP to provide more details for any comprehensive answer.

Comment: @Ayoola Olapo The approval process is triggered by a trigger not by inbuilt approval process. So i can't add the field update in final approval process